# No boot with 4+ GPUs

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, cryptomining

I have a build intended for mining. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. My specs are as follows:

- mobo: ASUS TUF Z270 Mark 1 LGA1151
- CPU: Intel Pentium dual core G4600 3.6 LGA 1151 GHz
- RAM: (2x) Patriot Memory Viper Elite Series DDR4 4GB 2400MHz
- PSU: Corsair HXi Series, HX1200i, 1200 Watt
- GPU(s): (5x) XFX AMD Radeon RX 580

The system works beautifully if there are <= 3 GPUs connected via PCIe VER 007 16x to 1x powered risers.

If I connect one or more additional GPUs, I get a single beep code, and a warning that peripherals such as my keyboard cannot be located, followed by a black screen.

Having done a bit of reading, there were some suggestions to turn off Secure Boot. I did that to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must enable the **4g decoding option** on your motherboard **BIOS** options to boot the system with more than 4 GPUs on board. The option allows the system to enable or disable memory mapped I/O for a 64-bit PCIe device to 4GB or greater address space, because the primary VGA card should always be mapped below 4GB address.

You have also to update the **BIOS**, if the **4g decoding option** is not available on your motherboard BIOS. If you need help on how to update BIOS, you can check the wiki [BIOSUpdate](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BIOSUpdate). After that, in some cases, also disable the integrated graphics (if present) can help.